# Is it possible to route torrent upload and download differently?

Tags: bittorrent

More precisely,

Is it possible to route all bittorrent upload traffic to a VPN, will all download traffic still go through the classic interface ?

Comment: routing is done by-destination-address, so no, all traffic destined for off your LAN will take the default gateway out of your network (whether that be though a VPN tunnel or not). that said, Deluge lets you configure different proxies for each kind of connection, so if you have two proxy servers you wanted to use, that is possible. if your torrent software allowed you to bind different types of traffic to different interfaces, and thus implement different routing rules, but you have to find software that will do it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bittorrent is a **trading** protocol. That means, you will only get pieces of the file you want if you *upload* another part of it. The peers in a bittorrent network can only communicate with you over your IP. To make a successfull "trade", they therefore need to send something to the same IP they receive something from. So sadly, no, this is not possible.